# CSS Link style issue

Tags: html, css

My CSS looks like:

`.small, small:hover { color: #000000; }`

My HTML looks like:

```
<small>Small Text</small> 
<a href="#"><small>Small Text Link</small></a>
```

I'm trying to style the link in small i know its probably a simple problem but it colors the whole text and not just the link. Can anyone point me in right direction?

I'm using bootstrap so i don't want to change the color of a on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify that css rules for `small` element should be applied only if it is inside link (`a` element):

```css
a small, a small:hover { color: #000000; }
```

By the way, there is no point in providing the same rules for `a small` and `a small:hover`, just `a small` should be enough.